# Why does a centrifugal fan work better than an axial fan for high pressure drop systems?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, airflow, fan

I read that this is true, but I cannot understand why. Conversely, I heard that Axial fans are better for low pressure systems where large volumes of air need to be moved.

More info on centrifugal vs axial:

> Because of the high pressure they create, centrifugal fans are ideal for high pressure applications such as drying and air conditioning systems.

https://www.pelonistechnologies.com/blog/axial-vs.-centrifugal-fans

Comment: So how does each type work? What do you think lends them to specific apllications?

Comment: Updated with a link, which represents my understanding so far.

Comment: Much better material exists than that. Try Engineering thermodynamics Work and Heat transfer by Rogers and Mayhew but there are many other suitable references

Comment: Thanks. I will look into text books.

Answer (score 1):

If a fan has a shroud, only axial motion contributes to flow through the fan.

If the fan is missing a shroud, notice that the area as you move radially increases. This increase helps convert energy into pressure, much like a diffuser. If you want flow rate, even mass flow rate, spending energy on pressure is not as beneficial as spending it on acceleration.